# Where can I download old versions of OS X Server?

Tags: osx-server

I am unable to install the Mac App Store version of OS X Server on my machine, which is using an older version of OS X. I need the OS X Server app to begin Xcode continuous integration.

[image: Can't install OS X Server]

> We could not complete your purchase.
>
> Server can't be installed because OS X version 10.10.1 or later is required.

OS X Server seems to only be distributed through the Mac App Store. Is there any way to download and install an older version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for "OS X Server" on the Mac App Store only returns one result for the latest version, which can only be installed on the latest version of OS X.

However, old versions of OS X Server can still be downloaded from the Mac App Store via a direct link.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203137

- OS X 10.9 Mavericks

  - OS X Server 3.2.2
    https://itunes.apple.com/app/id714547929?mt=12
- OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

  - OS X Server 2.2.5
    https://itunes.apple.com/app/id537441259?mt=12

Comment: I'm looking for Server 5.1.0 and can't find it there.

Comment: As of May 2019, this appears to be another dead-end search for Mac OS X Server.

Comment: @David the App Store links still seem to work for me.